# Transform test data when using a persistent model

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessing, pickle

I'm quite new to data science and only slowly following the necessary steps to get valid results using scikit-learn. As far as I understand you fit and transform the training data and only transform the test data (using the parameters retrieved by the earlier fitting). For my project a persistent model is necessary, for that I export the trained model using joblib.

When applying the model on test data later, is there a way to retrieve the parameters (for transformation) generated during the training process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way that you use joblib to persist your saved model, you should persist the transformers that you use in the pipeline too. So for example if you're using `StandardScaler()` and `OneHotEncoder()`, those also need to be `joblib.dump()`ed so you can import them into your prediction script.

The simplest way to achieve this is to add both transformers and estimator into a [Scikit Learn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and use joblib to persist that.